# How to structure AWS Elastic Beanstalk production and staging environments with web and worker tiers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I'm planning on transfer an application from Heroku to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. On the Heroku, I have two different applications, one for staging and the other for production, and both have their web and workers dynos.

I'd like to setup something like that on AWS EB. I've read the difference about Web Tier and Worker Tier, but here goes some questions:

Do I setup two different applications for production and staging? Or the same application and two different environments? If so, I would have to create 4 environments, two for production web/worker and two for staging web/worker? What's the correct structure? I'll use the same Rails application for web and worker. In that case, will I have to deploy them separate or is there a command to deploy both environments together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, AWS Elastic Beanstalk later has created a solution for that called Environment Links:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/11/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-environment-links/

With that feature, we're now able to link both environments with the same code (so we deploy it only once instead of twice). To make the worker run the worker process and the web to run the web server, you can set different environment variables and customize the EB initialization scripts to check for those vars and run specific process.

Comment: I understand you are the original poster, but your answer doesn't really answer the question. It explains how to get a worker and web to talk to eachother, but it doesn't answer any of your questions about how to deploy, how to have different environments, and no mention of how to "structure" on AWS.

Comment: That's true Nick, I'll edit so I can make it more clear.

Comment: @RicardoNacif how does linking the 2 environments get the same code deployed to each?

Answer (score 5):

> I'll use the same Rails application for web and worker.

This tells me that you should have a single application. Applications manage application versions, which is basically just deployment history.

You will want to create 4 environments. This allows you to "promote to prod" by cname swapping, or by deploying a previously deployed version.

You will have to deploy your web/worker separately, but you could very easily create a script that deploys to both at the same time.

Comment: I just want to add that you can use environment variables to choose what "profile" (prod or staging)  to use. So your version and configuration should be the same, except environment variables.

Comment: Now I got it. So if I want to change any env var on production, I'll have to do that on 2 different EB environments (prod-web and prod-worker) right? AWS should rethink about that, it's not the smartest thing to do... Thanks sap1ens!

Comment: @RicardoNacif I think the real question is, why are your worker/web using the same code, and why would you want them to always look the same?

Comment: @NickHumrich just because is a Rails application and web/workers share the same model logic. In the future we'll be able to break things into separate gems, but I've just joined a new company and we have to move it to AWS EB so there's no much I can do about that.

Comment: @RicardoNacif understood. Just note that beanstalk is an opinionated service that is designed around best practices. So until you follow best practices, you'll have some annoyances.

Comment: For a ["highest level of resource and security isolation"](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) (ex: like a product in US health sector that stores or process PHI), use different AWS sub-accounts for prod and non-prod environments. You can create those accounts with AWS Organizations or [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/controltower/) (for compliance in a box)